# ECDH in OpenSSL

Tags: c, openssl

I have a question about ECDH in the OpenSSL library.

In file 'ecdhtest.c' at 159 line, we can confirm the value of private key as follows:

`BN_print(out, a->priv_key);`

But, the error happened when I built using Makefile.

```
ecdsatest.c:221:22: error: incomplete definition of type 'struct ec_key_st'
    BN_print(out, key->priv_key);
                  ~~~^
../include/openssl/evp.h:147:16: note: forward declaration of 'struct ec_key_st'
        struct ec_key_st *ec;   /* ECC */
               ^
1 error generated.
```

I think that the type of `key->priv_key` is `BIGNUM`.

I would like to confirm the value of the private key.

If you have some idea, please help me.

Comment: move the `ec_key_st` full definition into the header file from wherever it is right now, so the fields would be visible for everyone. Don't forget to revert your changes afterwards...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The definition of `struct ec_key_st` is held opaque by intent. It is defined in `ec_lcl.h` from the openssl distribution, which is not part of the public interface. In version 1.0.1k, it looks like this:

```
struct ec_key_st {
    int version;
    EC_GROUP *group;
    EC_POINT *pub_key;
    BIGNUM   *priv_key;
    unsigned int enc_flag;
    point_conversion_form_t conv_form;
    int     references;
    int     flags;
    EC_EXTRA_DATA *method_data;
} /* EC_KEY */;
```

but it may not be stable from version to version.

However, you *can* obtain the private key using the accessor function

```
const BIGNUM *EC_KEY_get0_private_key(const EC_KEY *key);
```

which would be the clean way to do that.

Comment: Thank you for answering my question. I conformed the private key using 'EC_KEY_get0_private_key'.